# App ID and Bundle Seed ID in multiple applications with ASPN, InApp Purchase, and other

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, app-id

I will create **multiple sale versions** of the same application with push notifications feature:

- CoolApp (full version)
- CoolApp Free (free, features limited
  version)
- CoolApp InApp (free version
  upgradable to full via InApp
  Purchase)

While registering for App ID in Apple Program Portal is possible to create "Bundle seed ID": "The Bundle Seed ID portion of your App ID can be utilized to share keychain access between multiple applications you build with a single App ID"

Is possible to create only one App ID, for example: "**XDFGYE6TR4.com.company.coolapp**" and use it for all three versions of **CoolApp**, with enabled push notifications and in app purchases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  The App ID is what controls each app's capability to share keychain access.

The key here is the "...between multiple applications you build with a single App ID" portion.

App ID is not the bundle.  "com.company.coolapp" is the App ID and is what controls keychain access...as well as things like whether it can be push enabled, etc.

Unfortunately what you want, it seems, is "using a wildcard App ID".

This cannot be done if you want to use push and in-app purchase.

Remember, though...Apple has frowned on having both a "Lite" version as well as an "in-app" updatable version.  One or the other.  Recently they have been pushing the "in-app" updatable...it makes them more money.

Comment: Do you have references for "Apple has frowned on having both a "Lite" version as well as an "in-app" updatable version. One or the other"? Thanks.

Comment: hi, i cant find the button for generating new bundle seed id anymore. what happened? what should i do?

Comment: The language has changed now. I think you can share the same Keychain access as long as you "use the same bundle Seed ID for each of your application's App IDs." I.e., App IDs can be different.