# importance of Bundle Seed ID during Create App ID? (Apple Provisioning Portal)

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I am unsure about the importance of the Bundle Seed ID when creating a new App ID in the Apple Provisioning portal.

What should I consider when selecting a Seed ID?

When do I need to use an existing Seed ID?

On the iOS provisioning portal I found when creating a new app id you can select an existing Bundle Seed ID for your new app. I’m wondering if we should use the same AppID prefix between the free and paid versions and if so, why? I’d like to know the advantages and disadvantages.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example App ID: ABCDE12345.com.foocompany.*

ABCDE12345 is the Bundle Seed ID (generated by Apple).

com.foocompany.* is the Bundle Identifier of the App ID and the Bundle Identifier in your Xcode project must start with ‘com.foocompany.’ and the asterisk can be replaced with a string of your choosing,

So, for your answer: The Bundle Seed ID is generated by Apple, so you don't have to worry about that. It gets created automatically.

Take a look on information about Wildcard app ID's. It makes it possible to get more apps on the same license!

Comment: On the iOS provisioning portal I found when creating a new app id you can select an existing Bundle Seed ID for your new app. I’m wondering if we should use the same AppID prefix between the free and paid versions and if so, why? I’d like to know the advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: "The Bundle Seed ID portion of your App ID can be utilized to share keychain access between multiple applications you build with a single App ID". The key here is the "...between multiple applications you build with a single App ID" portion.

App ID is not the bundle. "com.foocompany.*" is the App ID and is what controls keychain access...as well as things like whether it can be push enabled, etc.

Unfortunately what you want, it seems, is "using a wildcard App ID". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146097/app-id-and-bundle-seed-id-in-multiple-applications-with-aspn-inapp-purchase-and

Comment: hi, i cant find the button for generating new bundle seed id anymore. what happened? what should i do?

Comment: Technical Note TN2311 may also be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html