# Creating Lite version of my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios5, app-store, apple-push-notifications, app-id

I have created a Pro version of my app and uploaded to appstore. Now I want to create a Lite version of the app. I have followed following steps:

1. Duplicate the current Target
2. Rename the Duplicated Target
3. Rename the Duplicated Info.plist File
4. Change the Icons in the Duplicated Info.plist file to use the Lite Version Icons
5. Change the Bundle Identifier to match with the bundle identifier from Apple for the Lite Version
6. Edit Build Properties of the Duplicated Target

   - Add C / C++ Compiler Flags
   - Change the Product Name
   - Change the name of the Info.plist file to the name of the Duplicated Info.plist File
7. Add Logic to code to separate features of Lite and Full version.

I am all clear with the steps. The problem is I am using push notification service in my app. So how can I manage if I create different appID for Pro version and Lite version? I have to create different certificates right?
And there is another server application is running to control the push notification, so which certificate should I use at the server? Do i have to create another server application?

Thank you.

Comment: i just got a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146097/app-id-and-bundle-seed-id-in-multiple-applications-with-aspn-inapp-purchase-an so should I go with 'in-app purchase'?

Comment: if your app is not on the appStore yet then yes, with in-app purchase you can keep the same appId for lite/full. otherwise you will need two certificates.

Comment: @rokjarc my full version app is already at the appstore, can I implement the in app purchase only in lite version?

Comment: it's usually done that way. do you have a way (in your existing app) to find out, if the app was allready installed. what i mean is - are you writing anything to NSUserDefaults?

Comment: to find out what? the app is already in appstore and some are downloaded it. And i am nothing writing to NSUserDefaults. Can i upgrade my Lite version app to full version through in-app purchase? Using same app id?

Comment: to find out if your app was already installed - so the users, who allready have full app, wouldn't end up with a lite version. this makes sense only if you want to use the same appId (which means the same binary, same SKU in the app store) for both versions.

Comment: anyhow: i think the cleanest way would be to create a separate (lite) app and use a separate certificate for push notifications